# Parsing CSV log file in Python

Tags: python, csv, parsing, pandas

I have a web log data which I need to parse and load into Pandas dataframe to rum some Machine learning algorithms. The problem is that the input file, though a csv isn't in straight forward comma seperated format. It includes url parameters and json format key value pairs, which i also need to parse, and all of this is encoded in unicode.

The input CSV looks like this:

```
[Row(firstKey=u'some_alpha_nemeric', anotherKey=u'another_alpha_nemeric_value',referrer=u'//google.com/images/etc.html?fid=283000185&flowid=17001,something_in_json_format={u'availibility': u'available', u'lifecycle': u'-'},
[Row(....
```

The output pandas dataframe should read values for all keys, including the URL parameters (like referrer url in above example) and jSON values

So basically I need an output pandas dataframe with columns `firstKey, anotherKey, refferrer, fid, flowid, something_in_json_format.availibility, something_in_json_format.lifecycle`

I've started writing a basic csv reader script

```
with open('c:/Documents/web.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
 myreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
 for row in myreader:
     print ' '.join(row)
```

But I'm clueless on how to parse this complex structure and load into pandas.

Comment: I don't get the "[Row()..." thing, it doesn't look like a CSV file. can you be a bit more specific with a csv's row example?

Comment: That will be fun to parse, good luck.  I believe the dict format is the closest to what you have in the file and that pandas will convert to a frame.  eg `df_dict = [{'firstKey' : 'some_alpha_nemeric', 
            'anotherKey' : 'another_alpha_nemeric_value', 
            'referrer' : '//google.com/images/etc.html?fid=283000185&flowid=17001',
            'something_in_json_format' : {'availibility': 'available', 'lifecycle': '-'}}]

df = pd.DataFrame(df_dict)`

Comment: @JuanAlbarracínPrados yes though it has .csv extension, but its not in proper csv format. Don't give attention to the csv extension, let's say its txt file, how should i write a program to parse it and load it into pandas?

Comment: @BobHaffner Thanks for the input. But still I would need some help on the script which parses the key,value pairs, URL params and json values, line  by line, so that I could add them in dict, and load it into pd dataframe. If you could give some code snippet example, or refer some source with similar example, that would give me a great starting point.

Comment: Assume it as a ```txt``` file and create a ```json``` out of it. Creating a json seems pretty straight forward to me and then using ```pandas.read_json()``` you can create a dataframe out of it.